# How to use angularjs translate inside of infowindow?

Tags: angularjs

I want to use translate inside of infowindow. Translate is working with html filter but doesn't work inside infowindow. How can I use in controller? What is different way?

```
var app = angular.module('test', ['pascalprecht.translate']);

app.config(function ($translateProvider) {
    $translateProvider.translations('en', {
        province:"Province", 
        district:"District",   
    });
    $translateProvider.translations('tr', {
        province:"İl",
        district:"İlçe",   
    });
})

app.controller('controllerHome', ['$scope','$controller',
    function ($scope, $controller) {
      $scope.getDetail = function(id) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: $scope.SERVICE_BASE + "/v1/getPortfolioDetail",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $scope.createToken('/v1/getPortfolioDetail', {id: this.id.toString(),}),
            success: function (data) {
                if (data[0].price == null) {
                    var price = '<span class="mb-1 d-block"><strong class="text-secondary">Value </strong>: -</span>';
                } else {
                    var price = '<span class="mb-1 d-block"><strong class="text-secondary">Value </strong>: ' + data[0].price + ' TL</span>';
                }

                if (!t._popup) {
                    content = '<div class="d-block color1-lighten-15 p-1">' +
                        '<span class="mb-1 d-block"><strong class="text-secondary">{{'province' | translate}} </strong>: ' + data[0].city + '</span>' +
                        '<span class="mb-1 d-block"><strong class="text-secondary">{{'district' | translate}} </strong>: ' + data[0].town + '</span>' +
                        price +
                        '</div>';
                    compileContent = $compile(content)($scope);
                    t.bindPopup(compileContent[0]).openPopup();
                }
            }
        });
     }
    }
]);
```

Comment: You can inject `$translate` into your controller and use `$translate.instant`

Comment: Can you give me an example?